# How to extract regression coefficients from points(fitted()) function in R

Tags: r, regression, coefficients

I've recently created a linear regression model that used a -1 power boxcox transformation. In the plot, I'd like to back-transform the model to show both the untransformed (UT) and back-transformed model fits. To do this, I've been using the following code which transformed the dependent variable by ^-1 and then back-transformed the resultant model by ^-1. The reason that this produces slightly different models is because the regression is weighted according to the estimated covariation with an evolutionary tree.

```
plot(yvar~xvar, comp.data$data, pch=16, col="blue")

points(fitted(UTmodel)~UTmodel$data$data$xvar, col="blue", type="l") # fit line from untransformed

points(fitted(Tranformedmodel)^-1~BTmodel$data$data$xvar, col="red", type="l")
```

This actually works well (see image) but I'd like to know how to access the regression equation coefficients from the final line. I've tried directly raising the transformed co-efficients by ^-1 and using the coef() function but to no avail.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYIyp.png]